# Google Apps Script error with BigQuery.Jobs.query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a script that has been working fine for months, but has recently stopped working because of a syntax error.

Here is the section of the function that is causing problems:

```
  var projectId = '{{projectId}}';
  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  var request = {
    query: {{query}},
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
```

The error message is:

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [1:232]`

This is the line where `var queryResults` is defined.

Comment: most likely an error in `{{query}}`

Comment: The query runs fine in BigQuery, which suggests it is something else, but really struggling to think what it could be 

Comment: might help to include the query in the question